# I complained about a coworker and they know I did it. How can I handle the situation?

Tags: united-kingdom, unprofessional-behavior

Not so long ago, I was attending the office and it was pretty quiet; people aren't really attending so much despite company policy, myself included.

On this day some co-workers were socialising in the canteen area. They were talking rather loudly and obnoxiously and entirely about non-work related matters. I could hear what they were saying, including bad mouthing some of our colleagues from another office. They spent over an hour doing this.

Overhearing their conversations I was able to guess at who their high level manager may be, and I decided to let the manager know about these individuals and described one of them who appeared to be the leader of the group. I described them as "gossiping" to this higher up. The manager responded that they knew of the individual in question but didn't say anything else.

A few days later I noticed that the co-worker I had reported seemed to be making a lot of remarks out loud about "gossiping" and "slacking off" particularly when among some of the same co-workers. The rest of the co-workers have begun joining in.

This makes me uncomfortable for several reasons; I suspect they know a report was made, they seem to know it was me, and it would imply that somebody told them that it was me.

I want advice on how I can handle this situation. I don't think I can go and complain to the higher level manager about letting this other person know I complained, and I don't think my complaint was generally well received. I don't know this co-worker personally.

Comment: If they were being particularly annoying about it, you may not have been the only person who complained. Having taken it to management you're sorta stuck with it; I'd have first tried approaching them directly and saying "hey, could you hold it down or take it elsewhere? I'm having a bit of trouble focusing with the distracting conversation in my ears.'

Comment: What motivated you to report this behavior? What were you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry mate, you made your bed and now you have to lay in it. If it bothered you, you should have asked them (politely) to stop. Snitching anonymously to a their manager behind their is NOT going to make you any friends.

Answer (score 6):

Going to conjecture here since I'm not well versed at all with UK corporate etiquette:

Your coworker likely felt like the canteen area was a place that was more "liberating" than other locations.  It's not uncommon for coworkers to commiserate or complain in a space with peers, so this doesn't seem like particularly out of the ordinary.

You highlight that they did this for over an hour.  That...sounds like a typical lunch break length, at least to me as an American.  So in a positive spin, it could be translated as a group of coworkers complaining about work in the canteen over lunch.

How you spun it to the higher-up was unfortunate.  You projected an environment that may or may not have been real or practical.  Your claim about "gossiping" may or may not be 100% accurate, and it even sounds like the manager in question has their own predisposition for the people in question.  That is not...ideal.

So of course the next day, they're back at it and complaining about yet another thing that's got under their skin.  No surprises here.

---

How do *you* handle it?  You have two choices:

- **Ignore it, and don't make a big deal of it.**  People venting about work is a fact as assured as the sunrise.  It's not like they're doing this for the entire *day*, y'know.
- **Report to your manager, and describe how it's impacting *your* work.**  You don't need to go over anyone's head at this point or around anyone.  If you're feeling uncomfortable with the situation, take it to **your** manager and see what they offer as solutions.  Ultimately they're the ones who are responsible for your working considerations on the clock.

Comment: Agree and choice #1. If focus of complaint was not on content of the word spoken, but instead the volume of the speaking: 'talking rather loudly' and 'remarks out loud', then the blokes (assumed) would likely have just quieted things down a bit the next time. Now they may have been riled up, so recommend ignore it path and let them settle down again.

Answer (score 6):

I've read and re-read the question. As you've framed it - I'm inclined to say that (from the popular Reddit page) - YTA.

That is - people bitching about work, in the lunch room, presumably on their lunch break is perfectly okay.

Now, if they were throwing Racial Slurs or using particularly derogatory language - then you might have a point - but my spidey sense tells me that if they had done so, you would have lead with that, the fact you didn't tells me that they didn't either.

To answer your question which essentially 'How to Handle it' - You mind your own business. Anything said or overhead in the lunch room is fair game, especially if it's during a lunch break. The one caveat being the above using abusive language. To clarify - saying so-and-so from marketing is useless is **not** abusive.

If the issue is the volume at which they were talking - then rather than focussing on *what* was said - I'd say something like this to my direct manager:

"Hey Boss, I'm wondering if you can have a word with Management - some people take early or late lunches when the rest of us are still working and sometimes they get carried away and the noise can be a bit distracting - I'd like them just to tone it down a bit"

Which is pretty reasonable. The issue I suspect you'll find though is that if, as you say, your complaint wasn't well received - you are likely to burn whatever is left of the bridge with your colleagues in doing so.

Comment: YTA...........?

Comment: @LoremIpsum Reddit jargon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R/AmItheAsshole

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Bernhard.

Comment: Don't start nothing, won't be nothing.  I put this is the "If you make your bed hard it may be difficult to sleep" category.